# Redux Thunk - Async, chaining actions with Promises

Tags: asynchronous, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, axios

so I've been stumped on this problem for the last two days.

So in the app, there are multiple organizations. I also have an action to allow the user to switch between organizations.

The organization reducer:

```
import {
    FETCH_ORGANIZATION_LIST_REQUEST,
    FETCH_ORGANIZATION_LIST_SUCCESS,
    ORGANIZATION_ERROR,
    PICK_ORGANIZATION } from '../actions/types'

const INITIAL_STATE = { error: null,  organizations: [],  isFetching: false, currentOrganization: null, hasCurrentOrganization: false };

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCH_ORGANIZATION_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, isFetching: action.isFetching, error: null};
        case FETCH_ORGANIZATION_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, isFetching: action.isFetching, organizations: action.payload, error: null };
        case ORGANIZATION_ERROR:
            return { ...state, isFetching: action.isFetching, error: action.payload };
        case PICK_ORGANIZATION:
            return { ...state, currentOrganization: action.organizationId, hasCurrentOrganization: action.hasCurrentOrganization };
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

The fetch organization and pick organization calls are below:

```
export function fetchOrganizationList() {
    const url = `/organizations`;

    return (dispatch) => getData(
        FETCH_ORGANIZATION_LIST_REQUEST,
        FETCH_ORGANIZATION_LIST_SUCCESS,
        ORGANIZATION_ERROR,
        true,
        url,
        dispatch);
};

export function pickOrganization(organizationId) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: PICK_ORGANIZATION,
            organizationId: organizationId,
            hasCurrentOrganization: true
        })
    }
};
```

I've got a getData call which is also used for other server calls:

```
export function getData( actionRequest, actionSuccess, errorType, isAuthReq, url, dispatch) {
    const requestUrl = API_URL + url;
    let headers = {};

    dispatch({
        type: actionRequest,
        isFetching: true,
        error: null
    });

    if(isAuthReq) {
        headers = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Token ' + cookie.load('token')} }
    }

    axios.get(requestUrl, headers)
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({
                type: actionSuccess,
                isFetching: false,
                payload: response.data
            });
            return response.data; 
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            errorHandler(dispatch, error, errorType)
        })

}
```

And finally I have a OrganizationSelector.jsx container component, which allows me to pick and choose the current organization.

```
import React, {
    Component,
    PropTypes,
} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { fetchOrganizationList, pickOrganization, fetchAndPickCurrentOrganization } from '../../actions/organizations';

import Picker from '../../components/Picker';

class OrganizationSelector extends Component {


    componentDidMount() {

        this.props.fetchOrganizationList();
    }

    render() {
        const { isFetching, error, organizations, dispatch } = this.props;

        let count = !isFetching ? organizations.count : 1;

        return (
            <div>
                {isFetching && !error &&
                <li>Loading...</li>}
                {!isFetching && !error && count > 1 &&
                <Picker
                    currentOrganization={organizations.results[0].name}

                    options={organizations.results}
                    onSubmit={pickOrganization()}
                />
                }
                {!isFetching && !error && count === 1 &&
                <div>
                    {organizations.results[0].name}
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

OrganizationSelector.propTypes = {};
OrganizationSelector.defaultProps = {};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    organizations: state.organization.organizations,
    isFetching: state.organization.isFetching,
    error: state.organization.error
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        fetchOrganizationList: bindActionCreators(fetchOrganizationList, dispatch),
        // pickOrganization: bindActionCreators(pickOrganization, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrganizationSelector);
```

Now where I am getting problems is chaining the actions together in the same action creator.I want to pass the picOrganization action after the fetchOrganizationList action finishes fetching, I tried doing a number of things, by having a fetchListAndPickCurrentOrganization() function.

```
export function fetchListAndPickCurrentOrganization() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchOrganizationList())
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response) // This is where the Pick organization call will go
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log('error')
            })
    }
};
```

I also tried making the axios call directly in the fetchOrganizationList() call, but I keep getting .then as undefined, which I'm guessing is because the returned response from the axios call isn't getting passed through to .then.

I've tried a number of things, but the goal is to run these two calls on first mounting of the app, the pickOrganization call will of course be used again to switch between organizations.

Comment: Have you tried returning your `axios.get(...)` call from `getData`? Without this the promise isn't exposed and you can't call `.then(...)` after dispatching the action.

Comment: Yes so chaining the calls together like so, seems to work `axios.get(...).then(...).then(...)`

Comment: But generally I wanted to break the code down as much as possible. Although I'm open to switching to Fetch if thats easier to work with, with Redux thunk. edit: Ah I see what you mean, no I haven't tried doing that, will have a look at trying that.

Comment: @Ashley 'CptLemming' Wilson that seems to have fixed the promise issue! I guess I didn't realize I had to return that in this case! Its always something as simple as that.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: In passing - you should probably answer your own question and mark it correct so as to help others in the future (with a shout-out to Ash of course).

Comment: Ok sure thing. Will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was quite simple, I had to return the axios.get request, as it wasn't getting returned in my initial solution, which is why nothing was getting passed to .then, and it was undefined.

```
export function getData( actionRequest, actionSuccess, errorType, isAuthReq, url, dispatch) {
    const requestUrl = API_URL + url;
    let headers = {};

    dispatch({
        type: actionRequest,
        isFetching: true,
        error: null
    });

    if(isAuthReq) {
        headers = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Token ' + cookie.load('token')} }
    }

    return axios.get(requestUrl, headers)
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({
                type: actionSuccess,
                isFetching: false,
                payload: response.data
            });
            return response.data; 
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            errorHandler(dispatch, error, errorType)
        })

}
```

Thank you @Ashley 'CptLemming' Wilson for solving this for me.